# sqlite3 extension-functions: The specified module could not be found

Tags: dll, sqlite

I'm trying to get the `extension-functions` sqlite3 extension to load. The C file can be found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib) at the bottom.

I'm running win10 and using VS2015. I have compiled (with no errors) both 32 and 64 bit versions to .dll and tried loading them using the sqlite3 shell with the same error. (Using both 32 and 64 bit versions of the sqlite3.dll file respectively). Below I'm trying to load the extension using 32bit sqlite.

```
sqlite> select load_extension('C:\sqlite\ext32.dll');
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
sqlite> select load_extension('C:\sqlite\ext64.dll');
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

I used this command for compiling 32bit `cl extension-functions.c -link -dll -out:ext32.dll`. Then I ran `vcvarsall x64` and ran `cl extension-functions.c -link -dll -out:ext64.dll` for the 64bit version.

Comment: Leave off the extension? And since you're not giving a path, make sure it's in your sqlite3 shell's working directory.

Comment: I want to use the median function given by the extension... I've also updated my post to show the difference in error between 64 and 32 bit and made sure the dll was in the path.

Comment: The documentation states that "For security reasons, extension loaded is turned off by default and must be enabled by a prior call to `sqlite3_enable_load_extension()`". That is, you should rebuilt the sqlite3 program to allow loadable extensions.

Comment: `Note that the command-line shell program has already enabled extension loading for you (by calling the sqlite3_enable_load_extension() interface as part of its setup) so the command above works without any special switches, setup, or other complications.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extension-functions.c` doesn't export any function (aka 'procedure'), so, as is, the output DLL is pretty useless.

The SQLite shell expects a function named `sqlite3_extension_init` as stated in the [Programming Loadable Extensions](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#write) SQLite documentation chapter.

So, you just have to modify `extension-functions.c` like this (around line 1837).

Before:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_SQLITE_EXTENSIONS_AS_LOADABLE_MODULE
int sqlite3_extension_init(
    sqlite3 *db, char **pzErrMsg, const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi){
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
  RegisterExtensionFunctions(db);
  return 0;
}
#endif /* COMPILE_SQLITE_EXTENSIONS_AS_LOADABLE_MODULE */
```

after:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_SQLITE_EXTENSIONS_AS_LOADABLE_MODULE
#ifdef _WIN32
__declspec(dllexport)
#endif
int sqlite3_extension_init(
    sqlite3 *db, char **pzErrMsg, const sqlite3_api_routines *pApi){
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
  RegisterExtensionFunctions(db);
  return 0;
}
#endif /* COMPILE_SQLITE_EXTENSIONS_AS_LOADABLE_MODULE */
```

Comment: Ok, this is indeed fixes it using `cl`, thanks. I had actually got it working by installing mingw and compiling with `gcc`. `gcc` correctly exported the function without any of the above modifications. `gcc` version also runs ever so slightly faster.