# SQLite compiling extension Windows x64 with mingw-w64

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, gcc, mingw-w64

Specifically I am trying to compile the [CSV virtual table extension](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html). I followed the basic instructions [here](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) for mingw gcc, though I am using mingw-w64 gcc.

It compiles fine, but then gives this error trying to load it (via python 3.8 x64 SQLite3 library):  `The specified procedure could not be found`

I have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266158/sqlite3-extension-functions-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found), but I do not think it applies here as the CSV source does have the proper template for a SQLite extension and I have built it successfully in the past as a 32-bit DLL using mingw.

Has anyone successfully used mingw-w64 to build SQLite extensions or should I be looking at another compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided on the [SQLite forum](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/35168503fb) is that there is nothing wrong with how I was compiling, but rather how I was loading it: on older versions of SQLite, `load_extension` expects to have forward-slashes in the path to the dll, not backslashes.

There are also detailed recommendations for what gcc flags to use, so if you are having similar issues, take a look at that forum post.